# Unable to get html string stored in json string

Tags: javascript, c#, json, serialization, json.net

I have the following text:

```
Hello <b>User</p>
```

I am storing it as JSOn string in the database so as to use it later to deserialize it. Below is the JSON string sent to DB in MyProperty column:

```
{"Html":"Hello <b>User</p>"}
```

In order to deserialize that string back to my object I am using NewtonSoft.JSON dll.

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(this.MyProperty);
```

When I deserialize it I am unable to get `"Hello <b>User</p>"` value back, it comes as null.

Note: If I am not string HTML in the JSON string it is returned back while deserializing.

Is there any limitation with html tags in JSON string?

My goal is store html tags in JSON string and get it back.

Edit:

Code of MyClass:

```
 public class MyClass
    {
        public string Html { get; set; }
        public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you also include what `MyClass` looks like?

Comment: As I mentioned if there are no html tags in the string i.e plain text it is deserialized back.

Comment: Is this.MyProperty a string? I tried this by making the json object a string and it deserializes just fine. I'm using .Net 4.5 though, not sure if that makes a difference.

Comment: [Works fine for me](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LIAIOr).  Please edit your question to include an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: [JSON.org](http://www.json.org) says there is no escaping for opening and closing tags, only for backslash and quote and control chars. Thus the JSON string is valid. I tried that string with an online Jason parser and it is parsed correctly. Problem must be somewhere else

Comment: Are you expecting the result to be in `this.myProperty` ? That's where you should pass in the JSON string, and you should return the result of `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` into a variable of MyClass. The Html property will then contain `"Hello <b>User</p>"` something like `MyClass result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>("{'Html':'Hello <b>User</p>'}");`

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = "{\"Html\":\"Hello<b>User</p>\" }";
    var myClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyClass>(json);
}

public class MyClass
{
    public string Html { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```